# How to change all options of all select tags using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I would like to make a list of `select` tag that they have two values, `yes` and `no`.
I've created it(with a `while` statement in the php).

now, I want to create a `select` tag with two values(`yes` and `no`) that it should change all `select` tags.ex: if I select `yes` option, all options must be `yes`.

```
    <input onclick="toggle(this)" id="#select-all" type="checkbox" name="one"/><p>all</p>    
    <select data='beauty' name="txt" id="txt" onchange="setSelectBoxByText(this.getAttribute('data'), this.options[this.selectedIndex].text);">
    <option value="id_yes">yes</option>
    <option value="id_no">no</option>
    </select>


    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <table style="width:100%">

    <?php

        $result = mysql_query("my query...");


        while($row=mysql_fetch_object($result)){

    echo "<tr>
        <td>
        <input type='checkbox' name='one'/><p style='display:inline;font-size:14px;color:#fff'><a style='color:#fff' href='#'>$row->title</a></p>
        </td>

        <td align='left' style='padding-left:2px'>
            <select name='beauty' id='beauty'>
            <option value='id_yes'>yes</option>
            <option value='id_no'>no</option>
            </select>           
        </td>
    </tr>               

        ";
        }

    ?>       




    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set class on selects created in while and on select tag you want attach onchange event which will get all elements by className and set selection index same as your select tag selected index.

```
    <select id="globalSelection" onchange="changeSelection(this)">
        <option value="id_yes">yes</option>
        <option value="id_no">no</option>
    </select>

    var selects = document.getElementsByClassName('mySelect');
    function changeSelection(globalSelect) {
        for (var i = 0, select; select = selects[i]; i++) {
            select.selectedIndex = globalSelect.selectedIndex;
        }
    }
```